# Getting data from json and passing to url

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing

Want to send the json data to my url, when the json is received i receive all the json data on the url and not the data from 'resolvedQuery'

```
$update_response = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($update_response, true);

$results = $update['result']['resolvedQuery'];

$url = "https://autoremotejoaomgcd.appspot.com/sendmessage?key=APA91bEq&message=Data" . urlencode(json_encode($update));
```

Json Data

```
    {
  "id": "4ed272a3-b9a4-4f18-a67e-10e12e4f4149",
  "timestamp": "2017-12-10T10:07:54.282Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "turn livingroom light on",
    "action": "",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {
      "power-toggle": "on",
      "room": "livingroom"
    },
    "contexts": [],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "19764ecc-715c-4b25-960f-9845f2aef1f9",
      "webhookUsed": "true",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "webhookResponseTime": 503,
      "intentName": "lights"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "speech": "Ok, Turning livingroom light on",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "Ok, Turning livingroom light on"
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 206,
    "errorType": "partial_content",
    "errorDetails": "Webhook call failed. Error: Webhook response was empty.",
    "webhookTimedOut": false
  },
  "sessionId": "395d3517-05da-42ac-9037-dadac519ab0b"
}
```

How do i get data from 'resolvedQuery' and send it to my URL

Comment: What happens when you do `echo $results;`?

Comment: Can you show full Json data? Which thing is repeating in Json?

Comment: added the full json data..  when i echo $results; think shows on my php page..

Comment: Nothing is repeating in your Json, its static one?

Comment: Maybe you were meant to use `$url = "https://autoremotejoaomgcd.appspot.com/sendmessage?key=APA91bEq&message=Data" . urlencode(json_encode($results));`

Comment: try like this $update[0]['result']['resolvedQuery'];

Comment: when i change it to $results i get the word 'null' on the url.. i have change it to  $update[0]['result']['resolvedQuery' and still getting 'null'

Comment: @Null3rs you are getting `null` because your `json_decode` is unsuccessful`, meaning you have invalid JSON in `$update_response`.

Comment: @Acidic if i change it from urlencode(json_encode($results)) to urlencode(json_encode($rupdate)) the full data gets sent.. what would you suggest to do to get it to be successful

Comment: @Null3rs Can you tell me what is the result if you write `echo $results`

Comment: @Acidic added echo $results but i dont get any results on my page

Comment: @Null3rs Can you post the results of `echo $update`

Comment: @Acidic how do i get the results as when i put echo $update nothing showing on the page

Comment: @Acidic echo $update is just showing null

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provided, you have the following line of code

```
$url = "https://autoremotejoaomgcd.appspot.com/sendmessage?key=APA91bEq&message=Data"
        . urlencode(json_encode($update));
```

You are appending to the URL parameter `message` the results of `json_decode($update_response, true)`. `$update_response` contains all the decoded JSON data posted by the HTTP request which is not what you want.

I believe what you want is a new parameter called `resolved-query` to be set to the results of `json_decode($result, true)`.

**Try chaninging your `$url` variable to the following:**

```
$url = "https://autoremotejoaomgcd.appspot.com/sendmessage?key=APA91bEq&message=Data&resolved-query="
        . urlencode(json_encode($result));
```

URL will be set to the following string:

```
https://autoremotejoaomgcd.appspot.com/sendmessage?
    key=APA91bEq&
    message=Data&
    resolved-query=turn+livingroom+light+on
```